# Android studio set up is not shown the installation popup in Windows 10

Tags: windows, android-studio, windows-10

I just downloaded Android Studio(android-studio-ide-192.6241897-windows) for 64 bit.While clicking on this set up, it will ask, Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?

I have given yes,Then it won't shown any popup for installing android studio. But android setup running on background. I have tried multiple times and also restarted the system. But I'm still having this same problem.

How can i rectify and install the android studio in my system

Comment: What os is it?...

Comment: I am using windows10

Comment: Maybe you have clicked to install things in background, if it's that you'll see an animation in the bottom right corner and you can see the details or maximize it just by clicking on it